# Android MVVM + Room creating LiveData RecyclerViewItem objects by other LiveData objects

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

I have Room Entity Class "Symptom" with name of Symptom and id of it.

```
@Entity(tableName = "symptoms")
data class Symptom(
    @PrimaryKey @NonNull val id: Int,
    val name: String) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Symptom $id: $name"
    }
}
```

I'm getting it in the following classses:

**SymptomDao**

```
@Dao
interface SymptomDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM symptoms WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1")
    fun getSymptom(id: Int): Symptom

    @Query("SELECT * FROM symptoms")
    fun getAllSymptoms(): LiveData<List<Symptom>>
}
```

**SymptomRepository**

```
class SymptomRepository(private val symptomDao: SymptomDao) {

    fun getSymptom(id: Int) = symptomDao.getSymptom(id)

    fun getAllSymptoms() = symptomDao.getAllSymptoms()
}
```

**SymptomsViewModel**

```
class SymptomsViewModel(symptomRepository: SymptomRepository): ViewModel() {

    private val symptomsList = symptomRepository.getAllSymptoms()
    private val symptomsItemsList: MutableLiveData<List<SymptomItem>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getAllSymptoms(): LiveData<List<Symptom>> {
        return symptomsList
    }

    fun getAllSymptomsItems(): LiveData<List<SymptomItem>> {
        return symptomsItemsList
    }
}
```

I have RecyclerView with list of **SymptomItem** with Checkboxes to remember which Symptoms of a list users chooses:

```
data class SymptomItem(
    val symptom: Symptom,
    var checked: Boolean = false)
```

**Question**

My question is how can I get `LiveData<List<SymptomItem>>` by `LiveData<List<Symptom>>`? I have just started learning MVVM and I can't find a simply answer how to do that. I have already tried to fill this list in various ways, but It loses `checked` variable every time I rotate my phone. I'll be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to store which items are checked by storing their Ids in a List within the ViewModel. Then you'll have combine the list of your `Symptom` objects and the list of which items are checked, and generate the list of `SymptomItem` objects.

I'm going to use Kotlin Flow to achieve this.

```
@Dao
interface SymptomDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM symptoms")
    fun flowAllSymptoms(): Flow<List<Symptom>>
}
```

```
class SymptomRepository(private val symptomDao: SymptomDao) {

    fun flowAllSymptoms() = symptomDao.flowAllSymptoms()
}
```

```
class SymptomsViewModel(
    private val symptomRepository: SymptomRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val symptomsListFlow = symptomRepository.flowAllSymptoms()

    private val symptomsItemsList: MutableLiveData<List<SymptomItem>> = MutableLiveData()

    private var checkedIdsFlow = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<Int>())

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            collectSymptomsItems()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun collectSymptomsItems() =
        flowSymptomsItems().collect { symptomsItems ->
            symptomsItemsList.postValue(symptomsItems)
        }

    private fun flowSymptomsItems() =
        symptomsListFlow
        .combine(checkedIdsFlow) { list, checkedIds ->
            list.map { SymptomItem(it, checkedIds.contains(it.id)) }
        }

    fun checkItem(id: Int) {
        (checkedIdsFlow.value as MutableList<Int>).add(id)
        checkedIdsFlow.value = checkedIdsFlow.value
    }

    fun uncheckItem(id: Int) {
        (checkedIdsFlow.value as MutableList<Int>).remove(id)
        checkedIdsFlow.value = checkedIdsFlow.value
    }

    fun getSymptomsItems(): LiveData<List<SymptomItem>> {
        return symptomsItemsList
    }
}
```

In your Fragment, observe `getSymptomsItems()` and update your adapter data.

*The code is not tested, you may have to make small adjustments to make it compile.*

Comment: Thanks for advice. Unfortunately it still forgets which SymptomsItems are chosed (after phone rotation) and it updates RecyclerView every time I click checkbox so it loads the whole list every time I click item (I'm already showing checkbox animation so I don't want to refresh the whole RecyclerView).

Comment: Then the problem is in your Fragment and ViewHolder. You should add those to your question.

Comment: Here is SymptomViewModel:
https://github.com/whycody/CatsHealth/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/whycody/catshealth/symptoms/SymptomsViewModel.kt

Here is SymptomsFragment:
https://github.com/whycody/CatsHealth/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/whycody/catshealth/symptoms/SymptomsFragment.kt

Comment: You're injecting your ViewModel incorrectly in the Fragment, that is most likely the problem. Replace `SymptomsViewModel by inject()` with `SymptomsViewModel by viewModel()`. Requires a gradle dependency on `org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel`. Koin documentation: https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-android/viewmodel

Comment: To solve your other problem with RecyclerView updating the whole list each time, you'll have to implement a `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` for your Adapter. This will let RecyclerView figure out what parts of a list have changed when a change in the data has occurred. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-diffutil-databinding/#0

Comment: In `onBindViewHolder()` you'll have to set the checked status of the checkbox to what you have stored in the `SymptomItem`. This is for when the screen is rotated, as the view will be destroyed, you need to manually get it to visually match the data.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much for your help, you saved me :)